# Switch case with modulo

Tags: variable

I am trying to set up a LaTeX document that creates multiple versions of an exam. I am thinking of defining an integer variable early in the document and then use a switch-case construction depending on the modulo of that variable.

A C-like pseudocode looks like this:

```
switch(integervariable % 3){
case 0: What is your name?
case 1: What is your quest?
case 2: What is your favorite color?
}
```

How can I implement such a construction in LaTeX?

Ideally the construction would recognize the number of cases by itself.

Comment: Before of reinvent the wheel, you should know about  [AMC](https://www.auto-multiple-choice.net/).

Answer (score 1):

The `\ifcase` primitive can be used. The modulo must be calculated by more complicated formula because the `/` operator does rounding, no truncating.

```
\newcount\integervariable

\integervariable=7

\ifcase\numexpr \integervariable - 3*((\integervariable+2)/3 -1) \relax
case 0: What is your name?\or
case 1: What is your quest?\or
case 2: What is your favorite color?\fi
```

If you want to set general "modulo" then the implementation is more complicated because the `/` operator makes rounding symmetrical according to zero, **unfortunately** no truncating.

If you want to set an integer value from command line then another approach (using `\def\ivalue`) is more comfortable.

If you want to print `\def`ed `\ivalue` use `\ivalue`. If you want to print `\integervalue` from previus example, use `\the\integervalue`.

```
\ifx\ivalue\undefined \def\ivalue{7}\fi
\def\imodul{4}

\def\modulo#1#2{\ifnum#1=0 0\else(#1-#2*((2*#1-#2)/(2*#2)))\fi}

\ifcase\numexpr \modulo\ivalue\imodul \relax
  case 0: What is your name?\or
  case 1: What is your quest?\or
  case 2: What is your favorite color?\or
  case 3: If you need something more, open new tread...\else
  other cases\fi

\bye
```

You can set the `\ivalue` from Unix command line:

```
pdftex '\def\ivalue{5} \input' document
```

Comment: Can you give an example how to pass that parameter to the compiler from command line?

Comment: Can you give an example how you would print the counter (say, in arabic numbers)?

Comment: Can you please explain how that formula would change when computing modulo another number?

Comment: @shuhalo see the new version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of “fixed” randomizing?

Here you first define a set of questions, then call `\makeexam` with an integer argument *n*.

The command will choose the item *n* modulo the number of questions (actually with an order inversion to obviate the problem with 0).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_shuhalo_exam_questions_tl
\int_new:N \g_shuhalo_exam_modulo_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\cquestion}{m}
 {
  \item 
  \tl_item:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_count:n { #1 } - \int_mod:nn { \g_shuhalo_exam_modulo_int }{ \tl_count:n { #1 } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{setexam}{b}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_shuhalo_exam_questions_tl { #1 }
 }{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeexam}{m}
 {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_shuhalo_exam_modulo_int { #1 }
  \begin{enumerate}
  \tl_use:N \g_shuhalo_exam_questions_tl
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{setexam}
\cquestion{
  {What's your name?}
  {What's your quest?}
  {What's your favorite color?}
}
\cquestion{
 {Who's your favorite actor?}
 {What's your favorite pet?}
 {Can pigs fly?}
 {What's the ultimate question to life, universe and everything?}
}
\end{setexam}

\begin{document}

\section{exam}

\makeexam{1}

\section{exam}

\makeexam{2}

\section{exam}

\makeexam{3}

\section{exam}

\makeexam{4}

\section{exam}

\makeexam{5}

\section{exam}

\makeexam{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]